# How to work around on []= in removing middle relations rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I will simulate my problem through the next example, Suppose I've `student`s that could be related to `course`s, and the `course` contains more than one `student`. So, It is many to many relationship between students and courses, Consider the following code:

```rb
# student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_courses
  has_many :courses, through: :student_courses
end
```

```rb
# student_course.rb
class StudentCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :student
  belong_to :course
end
```

```rb
# course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_courses
  has_many :students, through: :student_courses
end
```

All the above is ok, but while I was trying to make a delete between these relation and make a callback in the middle table like

```rb
> c = Course.first
> c.students = [] # this perform a deletion correctly but can't be triggered by a call back
```

make `students` and empty array delete the relation correctly but it is not triggered by a callback.
while using `StudentCenter.where(something).destroy_all` will trigger `after_destroy` and so on.

my question is, How could I use the `= []` and keep the triggering as I somehow find the manipulation on the middle table is a little bit noisy in reading the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What callback do you want to trigger making `c.students` an empty array? What are you hoping to trigger it?

Comment: for example 'after_destroy' or 'after_commit' one (On the `StudentCourse` model), I just want the workaround of making it possible.
thanks for your comment @Mark

Comment: What is `StudentCenter`?

Comment: I'm sorry it is a typo, I mean `StudentClass` model. @Kris

Comment: Do you really have a model named `Class`? Are you aware of the fact that you are overwriting the Ruby core `Class` class?

Comment: Yes of course I'm aware of that, Actually this is just an example to explain my question. @medsantis

Comment: Does it really "perform the deletion" seems more like it just disconnects the students from the class. You could add `dependent: :destroy` to the relationship which should fire `destroy`.

Comment: I am not aiming just deletion, I'm aiming the hooks aftet using the []=, could u read the question carfully please. @engineersmnky

Comment: Can you please read my response carefully? If you were to add `dependent: destroy` to the relationship the `destroy` hooks should fire.  What you are using here is [`replace`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L243)  which calls [replace_records](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L410)

Comment: which calls [delete](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L189) which calls [`delete_or_destroy`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#L380) which calls [remove_records](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L107)

Comment: so on until you get to [`delete_records`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46b46e85c72f78e869a1b0038040849911c7e2c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb#L131) which has the hook for method :destroy which will fire call backs.

Comment: hmmmm, sounds interesting, I will give it a chance. thanks a lot @engineersmnky